# Custom cursor creating shivering svg

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying the customise the cursor when it is over some svg files to indicate to the user the possibility to click.

I stated for a tuto from https://websitebeaver.com/how-to-make-an-interactive-and-responsive-svg-map-of-us-states-capitals, changed jquery part to javacript and added the cursor's customisation (css and JS)

Unfortunately when I add those 2 lines of code :

```
    customCursor.style.top =  (e.pageY-10)+"px";
    customCursor.style.left = (e.pageX-10)+"px";
```

it makes the svg image hover "shivering"(sorry i do not find a better word to describe it). Some time the element is not even highlighted and also I have noticed the behavior is even different on chrome and firefox

[See the code](https://codepen.io/superdav/pen/wvKvoPq)

If I remove even one of those line the svg file looks good, no more cursor customisation but it behave good.

I am running out of ideas and I need fresh ones to solve it....

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment the cursor is intercepting pointer events and causing the hover to be removed. That then gets rid of the cursor, reinstating the hover etc etc etc.

Give the cursor the CSS property pointer-events: none;

```
cursor {
            position: absolute;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            border-radius: 50%;
            z-index:10;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
```